# When does Python write a file to disk?

Tags: python, file, unix, file-io, operating-system

I have a library that interacts with a configuration file. When the library is imported, the initialization code reads the configuration file, possibly updates it, and then writes the updated contents back to the file (even if nothing was changed).

Very occasionally, I encounter a problem where the contents of the configuration file simply disappear. Specifically, this happens when I run many invocations of a short script (using the library), back-to-back, thousands of times. It never occurs during the same directories, which leads me to believe it's a somewhat random problem--specifically a race condition with IO.

This is a pain to debug, since I can never reliably reproduce the problem and it only happens on some systems. I have a suspicion about what might happen, but I wanted to see if my picture of file I/O in Python is correct.

So the question is, **when does a Python program actually write file contents to a disk?** I thought that the contents would make it to disk by the time that the file closed, but then I can't explain this error. When python closes a file, does it flush the contents to the disk itself, or simply queue it up to the filesystem? **Is it possible that file contents can be written to disk after Python terminates?** And can I avoid this issue by using `fp.flush(); os.fsync(fp.fileno())` (where `fp` is the file handle)?

If it matters, I'm programming on a Unix system (Mac OS X, specifically). **Edit:** Also, keep in mind that the processes are not running concurrently.

Appendix: Here is the specific race condition that I suspect:

1. Process #1 is invoked.
2. Process #1 opens the configuration file in read mode and closes it when finished.
3. Process #1 opens the configuration file in write mode, erasing all of its contents. The erasing of the contents is synced to the disk.
4. Process #1 writes the new contents to the file handle and closes it.
5. Process #1: Upon closing the file, Python tells the OS to queue writing these contents to disk.
6. Process #1 closes and exits
7. Process #2 is invoked
8. Process #2 opens the configuration file in read mode, but new contents aren't synced yet. Process #2 sees an empty file.
9. The OS finally finishes writing the contents to disk, after process 2 reads the file
10. Process #2, thinking the file is empty, sets defaults for the configuration file.
11. Process #2 writes its version of the configuration file to disk, overwriting the last version.

Comment: Nope, when Python closes the file, the file has been flushed to disk. I'd say process #2 opens the file earlier than you think it does.

Comment: If several processes access a file concurrently and at least one of them writes to it, you have to synchronize the processes to get consistent results. That's not anything Python-specific.

Comment: Even when the OS does not write the data to the disk, it will guaranteed return the content of the file to the 2. process as long as it's flushed out of python, as there is a memory cache shared by anyone that accesses that file. (unless you're running the processes on different machines on a shared file system that isn't configured for consistency, or have race condition where you overwrite files.)

Comment: One possibility of problem could be: As soon as you open with `'w'` the contents are truncated.  If another process reads from it before it is written again, it will be empty.

Comment: I always rename my files to something like `config.xml.tmp`, and once it has been completed I replace the existing file by renaming it.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that the processes are **not** running concurrently. The first process ends before the second process loads.

Comment: @misfavor Add some debugging to process 1 where it checks that the file it produced are never empty, correlate the file names between process 1 and 2 so you know which run produced the erronous file

Comment: Agreed with nos.  Just before your final shutdown on process 1, Open the file again, and read it.  ..there's no mystery about whether or not there's floating data after a file's closed -- it must be either a condition where the first process fails to write, or a condition where the second process discards the read, if there's no possibility for concurrency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly not python's fault. If python closes the file, OR exits cleanly (rather than killed by a signal), then the OS will have the new contents for the file. Any subsequent open should return the new contents. There must be something more complicated going on. Here are some thoughts.

1. What you describe sounds more likely to be a filesystem bug than a Python bug, and a filesystem bug is pretty unlikely.
2. Filesystem bugs are far more likely if your files actually reside in a remote filesystem. Do they?
3. Do all the processes use the same file? Do "ls -li" on the file to see its inode number, and see if it ever changes. In your scenario, it should not. Is it possible that something is moving files, or moving directories, or deleting directories and recreating them? Are there symlinks involved?
4. Are you sure that there is no overlap in the running of your programs? Are any of them run from a shell with "&" at the end (i.e. in the background)? That could easily mean that a second one is started before the first one is finished.
5. Are there any other programs writing to the same file?
6. This isn't your question, but if you need atomic changes (so that any program running in parallel only sees either the old version or the new one, never the empty file), the way to achieve it is to write the new content to another file (e.g. "foo.tmp"), then do os.rename("foo.tmp", "foo"). Rename is atomic.

Comment: This is the best answer I can hope for, I suppose. Thank you!

Comment: As it turned out, an intern had edited a library function to spawn yet another Python subprocess (using the same module). After I rolled back that change, the problem seemed to go away. That probably also explains why the problem only happened on the intern's computer.